# How can I renew Kerberos Ticket in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, kerberos

In Linux I can run `kinit -R` or `krenew` to refresh Kerberos Ticket. How can I refresh Kerberos Ticket in Windows using command line? I tried to find by Google but found nothing that can help me.

Comment: kinit.exe is just a command-line tool release by MIT, download windows version from MIT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are talking about the Windows Kerberos implementation, there is no need to. Regardless you have a valid ticket, expired or no one. As soon as you log into Windows, LSA will retain your principal and password in memory and regain a fresh ticket as soon as it is necessary.

To verify that, download the Microsoft Resource Kit, you have `kerbtray.exe` and `klist.exe`. Purge the cache, check with `kerbtray`, access a Kerberos-protected resource and Windows will automatically issue an `AS-REQ` along with a `TGS-REQ`.

Comment: Could you tell me. how the system understand that the resource is kerberos-protected? It defines it by http response header WWW-AUTHENTICATE ?

Comment: @wazz The server requires the client to authenticate, the client asks the KDC and so on.

Comment: I asked because I don't get when the system detects that it should init tickets. I have a server application that returns WWW-AUTHENTICATE: Negotiate header in response for kerberos authentication. If tickets are already initialized in system, everything is ok. But receiving response from server with WWW-AUTHENTICATE: Negotiate doesn't make the client system to retry cached tickets. I created a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51203494/kerberos-cached-ticket-on-windows-machine-not-regenerated-after-user-unlock, please, maybe you have some assumptions about it?

Answer (score 4):

did you try using "klist purge" on the cmd? Doing that you can erase the cached tickets. To create the tickets again you only need to acces the protected resources again

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you specifically only want to renew the ticket in Windows? If you have a Java install and are happy to reauthenticate it has a [kinit tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/kinit.html) (in the bin directory in the java install dir).

Otherwise you could take a look at MITs beta [Kerberos for Windows](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/kfw-4.1/kfw-4.1.html).

Comment: If I understand right `kinit` can create new ticket, but not refresh existed. I have long process and this process needs one ticket only.

Comment: No, but it stores the new ticket in the ticket cache and depending on your client application it could be that it will happily renew service tickets with the new kinited TGT (ticket to get tickets). Check @Michael-o's answer though, it could be this is already handled for you. I'm much more familiar with Linux/Java Apps and kerberos.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to this is to call some system command 'whoami /groups', which forces LSA to renew tokens, since when you purge, they won't be renewed before related SGTs expiration. Java kinit makes no sense in SSO either